# How do I convert boolean values to integers?

Tags: ruby, boolean

I have a boolean value to check if it is true, then set a local variable. How do I refactor this so it is more Ruby-ish?

```
if firm.inflection_point
  inflection_point = 1
else
  inflection_point = 0
end
```

Comment: You may want to checkout the [code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions like these...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
inflection_point = (firm.inflection_point ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 29):

Another alternative is use of short-circuit operators:

```
inflection_point && 1 || 0


irb(main):001:0> true && 1 || 0
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> false && 1 || 0
=> 0
```

Answer (score 24):

If you just have that at one point, then [rudolph9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13537312/4565784) is good, but if you are having a similar kind of logic all over the place, then maybe it might make sense with general use in mind to monkey patch:

```
class FalseClass; def to_i; 0 end end
class TrueClass; def to_i; 1 end end

inflection_point = firm.inflection_point.to_i
```

Within Ruby, you should keep all of your logic dealing with truth values rather than `0` and `1`, but I guess you are dealing with some inputs or outputs from/to some external system that deals with `0` and `1`. Then, doing like this will make sense.

Comment: Adding to my personal library. Sometimes I have a series of comparisons or other logical tests I need to assemble together into one bitfield.

Comment: The problem is that `0 == true` so this might create a lot of confusion to someone who is going to support your codebase.

Comment: Monkey patching base core classes for such a simple thing is a very bad idea. You can catch some bug from a gem which does not expect to have such a method on true/false objects.

Answer (score 8):

In Ruby, `if` is an expression. There's no need to assign to a variable inside the `then` and `else` branches, just return the value you want and assign the variable to the result of the `if expression`:

```
inflection_point = if firm.inflection_point
  1
else
  0
end
```

In simple cases like this, it's more readable to write the entire expression on a single line:

```
inflection_point = if firm.inflection_point then 1 else 0 end
```

You can also use the conditional operator, which I personally find to be much less readable:

```
inflection_point = firm.inflection_point ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a conditional operation that is known as Ternary Operator
It's used in almost every language and it uses the symbols ? and :

```
inflection_point = firm.inflection_point ? 1 : 0
```

basically means, if the first condition evaluates to true (firm.inflection_point), return the value after "?" (1) otherwise, return the value after ":" (0)

Comment: First off: it's called the conditional operator, not the ternary operator. Saying "the ternary operator" doesn't even make sense, there's an infinite number of ternary operators. Secondly, you don't *need* the conditional operator in Ruby. You need it in "almost every other language" because in those languages `if` is a statement. But Ruby doesn't have statements, it only has expressions and thus `if` is an expression as well.

Comment: From The Ruby Programming Language, by D. Flanagan & Y. Matsumoto

_4.6.10 Conditional: ?:
The ?: operator is known as the conditional operator. It is the only ternary operator
(three operands) in Ruby. The first operand appears before the question mark. The second operand appears between the question mark and the colon. And the third operand appears after the colon._

 You'd better write to these guys and tell them to correct their book.

Comment: @thebugfinder The book is correct: it is called the **conditional** operator. Which is actually the point that @JörgWMittag is making. `` It may be the only ternary operator Ruby offers, but that does not make "the ternary operator" the correct name for it.

Comment: I'd argue if there is one apple on the desk it is "the apple" if there is sun in the sky it is "the sun".. if its the only ternary operator in the code it is "the ternary"  It is also "A" ternary.  I mean if we are being pedantic about vocab.

Answer (score 5):

It is not pure ruby solution but, You can use `ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new.cast(true)`

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed a lot of people proposed to Monkey Patch the ruby classes and implement the `.to_i` method on them in order to solve this problem.

I need to gently inform that the act of **Monkey Patching** the `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` [can be dangerous to your system](http://www.rubyinside.com/the-end-of-monkeypatching-4570.html)

A good approach is to use the [Ruby Refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) in order to make a much safer monkey patching. This approach restrict the changes on the *monkey patched* classes to the scope of your class.

- `lib/refinements/boolean_refinements.rb`

```rb
module BooleanRefinements
  refine FalseClass do
    def to_i
      0
    end
  end

  refine TrueClass do
    def to_i
      1
    end
  end
end
```

- `/your_class.rb`

```rb
require 'refinements/boolean_refinements'

class MyClass
  using BooleanRefinements

  # Here you can use true.to_i and false.to_i as you wish
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method:

`5 - bool.to_s.length`

This takes advantage of the fact that `'true'` has four characters, while `'false'` has 5.

Comment: This technically will work but it's convoluted and has a really bad code smell.

Comment: Yeah, but at least it won't increase your cyclomatic complexity like the ternary versions will. It's all about mitigating metrics.

Comment: It would in increase the cyclomatic complexity by `1`.  Ruby is a very dynamic language and should `inflection_point` be `nil` this is not going to work (putting conditionals on something that might be `nil` is common in ruby).  I see where you're coming from but in practice it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not a good practice… but I must admit it looks interesting. :D