# Most elegant way to add 1 to an integer if a boolean is true in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This will be an easy question for you Ruby experts: What is the most elegant way to add the value of 1 to an integer if a boolean is true?

For example, `extra_unit` is a boolean, and I want to add 1 to the `total` only if `extra_unit` is true.

```
total = unit_price * (units + (extra_unit ? 1 : 0 ))
```

Is that the most elegant solution, where, by "elegant", I mean in terms of compact but still readable code?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around what the bonus should mean? Should one get an extra unit? One pays 1 more if you get a bonus? What?

Comment: because you first caluclate the unit_price * units, and then you add 1 if you have a bonus. `total += 1 if bonus` would achieve that

Comment: after the edit you now pay an extra unit if you have a bonus?

Comment: Correct, thanks for the question.

Comment: it seems you had an error in your thinking? I doubt the logic of getting a bonus item should be in the price calculations...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert boolean values to integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537206/how-do-i-convert-boolean-values-to-integers)

Comment: Your code is compact, but elegant isn't necessary compact, it's also readable and obvious, and often, by trying to reduce the code to the smallest size, we sacrifice readability, which then sacrifices maintainability.

Comment: I have renamed "bonus" to "extra_unit" to be clearer about the intent, @TheCha͢mp, but my question is more about Ruby syntax than the logic here.

Comment: I think is readable -which is more important- and compact enough

Answer (score 3):

Given the caveat in my comment to the question above, and if I wanted it on one line and didn't care what it did to the mind of a coworker or my future self, I'd do something like this:

```
total = unit_price * (bonus ? units + 1 : units)
```

But, really, it could be written more verbosely without affecting the speed, which would increase the readability:

```
unit_price = 1.00
units = 1
bonus = true

unit_price * (units + (bonus ? 1 : 0 )) # => 2.0
unit_price * (bonus ? units + 1 : units) # => 2.0
multiplier = if bonus
              units + 1
            else
              units
            end
unit_price * multiplier # => 2.0
```

Those all return the same value so they're equivalent in result.

Running some benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'
compare do
  t1 {unit_price * (units + (bonus ? 1 : 0 ))}
  t2 {unit_price * (bonus ? units + 1 : units)}
  t3 {
    multiplier = if bonus
                  units + 1
                else
                  units
                end
    unit_price * multiplier
  }
end

# >> Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> t2 is similar to t1
# >> t1 is similar to t3
```

I ran the benchmarks multiple times, and the positions would swap, with t3 being marginally slower twice, but not enough that Fruity would consistently flag it as such.

So, as far as elegance goes, insisting that it being cryptic or as small as possible doesn't necessarily buy us anything useful, so instead go with readable and still fast. From experience, benchmarks are essential if you're going for elegant; Too often I've been surprised when I thought something would be faster because it was concise, when in comparison another more verbose expression ran circles around it.